# ASP.NET Chart Rendering issue in Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox, charts

I am working with an ASP.NET Chart control in an AJAX UpdatePanel that is being updated about 4 times a second with a new point added to it each time it is updated. This causes the chart to render 4 different images each second. I have been testing this functionality in a few browsers and have tried to tweak the chart settings to render the images as fast and smooth as possible, however it seems that Firefox is unable to load the chart this fast.

Right now I have this working well in IE, decent in Chrome, and not so well in Firefox. IE updates the chart and renders a new image up to 4 times a second flawlessly. In Chrome the image of the chart is rendered but is kind of flashy. When tested in Firefox a blank Image is shown where the chart should be and is not actually loaded until AFTER the AJAX UpdatePanel STOPS updating.

Is there a way to optimize the ASP.NET Chart control for Firefox? I have tried tweaking the AntiAliasing, ImageStorageMode, and ImageType properties with no visible improvement.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks.

EDIT: 
Here is my update panel with the chart in it.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Chart ID="chtPingData" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" 
                    ImageStorageMode="UseHttpHandler" ImageType="Jpeg">
                    <Series>
                        <asp:Series Name="Pings" ChartType="Line" ChartArea="MainChartArea">
                        </asp:Series>
                    </Series>
                    <ChartAreas>
                        <asp:ChartArea Name="MainChartArea">
                        </asp:ChartArea>
                    </ChartAreas>
                </asp:Chart>
                <asp:Timer ID="tmrAjax" Interval="250" runat="server" Enabled="False" 
                    ontick="tmrAjax_Tick">
                </asp:Timer>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: This seems like a problem with the generated markup and not the browser. If it works in IE but not a modern browser then it usually is the markup. But, without the markup or a link, anything is a wild guess.

Comment: I posted the ASP.NET code I am using. When the timer ticks a new point is added to the chart in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is unable to load/generate images that fast. The solution I found was to use a Javascript library that would generate a chart from a table using HTML5 which did not render images.

Answer (score 0):

Whould it not be better to consider Silverlight/Flash or render the chart via JavaScript and only sending the raw data?

I have had problems with updating an image even at the rate of one image per second..